# UWP: binding via ElementName is not updating ui

Tags: data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a simple `Page` with a `TextBlock` where I want to display its `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth`.

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="HaproPlace2.Views.Calibration.CalibrationView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="1080"
    d:DesignWidth="1920"
    x:Name="Page1">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Page1, Path=ActualHeight}" Foreground="LimeGreen" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

When the `app` starts, it shows the right value, but is not updating when resizing the `page/window`. Is there something special in `uwp` to get it automatically updating the `ui` if bound to a `dependencyProperty` via `ElementName`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the note [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualheight?view=winrt-19041#remarks).

> Although it [ActualHeight] has an ActualHeightProperty backing field, ActualHeight **does not raise property change notifications** and it should be thought of as a regular CLR property and not a dependency property.

So your options are:

- Subscribe to `SizeChanged` of Page and update your Text from there
- Create and use attached property (it's basically the same, but hidden in attached prop)

Answer (score 0):

You are not Using `Mode=TwoWay`, mandatory in order to have the value update constantly.